# App name not showing in outgoing webhook request

Tags: php, slack, slack-api

when ever I try to get the username from slack outgoing hook its showing default username as slackbot.it doesn't show the username of the actual person in this case Nawaf.
as u can see it should save the name "Nawaf" or "test" but it's saving "slackbot" what am I doing wrong?

[image: IMAGE 1]

[image: IMAGE 2]

[image: IMAGE 3]

slack outgoing webhook documentation
https://api.slack.com/custom-integrations/outgoing-webhooks

Comment: I guess its because its an app posting the messages, not an actual user. Besides, I recommend using Events API instead. They are way more powerful than the outdated Outgoing Webhooks

Comment: @ErikKalkoken so in event API i can get the username correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you don't get the username of the app message in your outgoing webhook request is most likely that this is not supported. Outgoing webhooks is a legacy feature of Slack and replaced by the [Events API](https://api.slack.com/events-api), which provide a similar functionality, but is way more powerful.

I tested it to verify your requirement and can confirm that you get the name of the app sending a message with the Events API from [message events](https://api.slack.com/events/message).

Here is an example of the message event you receive from a message posted by incoming webhooks (as PHP array):

```
array (
  'token' => 'XXX',
  'team_id' => 'T12345678',
  'api_app_id' => 'A12345678',
  'event' => 
  array (
    'text' => 'This is a line of text.
And this is another one.',
    'username' => 'magic-webhook',
    'bot_id' => 'B12345678',
    'type' => 'message',
    'subtype' => 'bot_message',
    'ts' => '1509969916.000102',
    'channel' => 'G12345678',
    'event_ts' => '1509969916.000102',
  ),
  'type' => 'event_callback',
  'event_id' => 'Ev12345678',
  'event_time' => 1509969916,
  'authed_users' => 
  array (
    0 => 'U12345678',
  ),
)
```

For messages posted by Slack apps you won't get the username in the message event directly, but you can then call the API method [`bots.info`](https://api.slack.com/methods/bots.info/test) with `bot_id` to get the app name.